# Storing Html into an array and then saving it in DB and retrieve that array - shows error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am storing some data in an array and then storing it in array.Everything worked fine. But due to requirements I had to store some HTML too in that array. Following code is a part of it

```
step2_data["data1"] = data1;

step2_data["color"] = color;

step2_data["data2"] = sectionArray;

var html = '<div class="here"></div>';

step2_data["drawing_door"] = html;
```

To retrieve data I do this

```
var stored_data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(
                get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "CONFIG_FILE",false));?>');
```

Everything worked fine untill I introduced HTML content storing.
I get Following Error

[image]

In console the array looks something like this

```
JSON.parse('[[{"step 2":{"drawing_door":"<div class=\"here\"><\/div>"}}]]');
```

Its a big array I am just showing the html part.

Any idea where I am going wrong or any other alternative if you guys can suggest.

Comment: You don't need to parse that

Comment: You have a syntax error, hard for us to answer unless you post your actual code

Comment: I know it's not what you want to hear but store HTML in DB isn't a good idea. You should prolly thing about some other option how to do it.  However to load HTML to a `js` variabile you dont need to add that aditional PHP `json_encode`to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access PHP array through javascirpt object, No need to store it as json string and parse it to convert into JavaScript object, simply you can do

```
var stored_data = <?php echo json_encode(
                get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "CONFIG_FILE",false));?>;
```

Comment: Ok but previously it was not showing any error untill I tried with html , Why didn't it showed the error before ?

Comment: it depends on dynamic data returning from that function.. and if it has ' or " then string should be break and not works. but in this case it should be work. let me know if it working or not?

Comment: I guess if the error what you think cause by HTML so try to fix the quote and double quote mark. Double quote "...'bla bla bla'..." is out side the single quote. So it will be var html = "<div class='here'></div>";

Comment: @HareshVidja : Yes It Works , but I wanted to know the reason why it was working before . Is single quote and double quote the main reason for bug as @TommyDo said other then `JSON.parse`

Comment: yes.. before may be your function data have not single quote that's why it was working.

Answer (score 1):

So I think that my solution is OK, isn't it? :D.

The error because when you put the HTML text into a variable as

```
var html = "something"
```

Now "something" are as string value. So inside the double all have to be as string. If you want to put the double quote inside, you have 2 solustions:

```
//add escape the special characters
var html = "<a href="\google.com"\></a>";
```

OR

```
//add single quote only inside
var html = "<a href='google.com' id='link' class='my_class' ></a>";
```

IF you put the double quote "..." inside double quote, that means you close the string and put the variable inside like:

```
var link = "google.com";
var html = "<a href=' "+ link +" '></a>";
```

I hope my explaination are clear enough. Sorry my english is not good enough to explain more detail.

Comment: I am not sure but I removed the `JSON.parse` and it worked ,. Though I will upvote your answer

Comment: I think so, but my issue is not out of the solution. Maybe it works for others. Thank for voting.